# R refClass Methods

Tags: r, object

I am using R refClass example below.

```
Person =  setRefClass("Person",fields = list(name = "character", age  = "numeric")
            ) ## Person = setRefClass("Person",


Person$methods = list(
              increaseAge <- function(howMuch){
                age = age + howMuch
              }
          )
```

When I store this program in a file called Person.R and source it, it does not show any errors.  Now I instantiate a new object.

```
p = new("Person",name="sachin",age=40)
```

And I try to invoke the method increaseAge, using `p$increaseAge(40)`, and it shows the following error

```
Error in envRefInferField(x, what, getClass(class(x)), selfEnv) :
  "increaseAge" is not a valid field or method name for reference class "Person"
```

I cannot figure out why it says that the method increaseAge is not a valid method name when I have defined it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get an error using your code. I would do something like this:

```
Person =  setRefClass("Person",
                      fields = list(name = "character", age  = "numeric"),
                      methods = list(
                        increaseAge = function(howMuch) age <<- age + howMuch
                      ))

> p = new("Person",name="sachin",age=40)
> p$increaseAge(5)
> p$age
[1] 45
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy.  Your code works for me as well.  But I don't understand what was the problem with my code?  I notice that you used "<<-" instead of "=".  The assignment operator is what I was missing I think.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a method independent of class definition, invoke the `methods()` *function* on the generator. Also, use either `<<-` or `.self$age =` for the assignment.

```
Person$methods(increaseAge=function(howMuch) {
    age <<- age + howMuch
    ## alterenatively, .self$age = age + howMuch or .self$age <- age + howMuch
})
```

Remember that R works best on vectors, so think of a `Persons` class (modeling *columns*) representing all the individuals in your study, rather than a collection of `Person` instances (modeling rows).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  Got the point.  I just transitioning to using OOPS for a R project. This helps.